# Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com Laravel

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

I am trying to send a mail to my email-id. I have followed all the steps that might required to send  a mail.

But it keeps on coming 2 errors

1. Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.#10060]
2. Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded.

my controller is

```
public function contact()
    {
   Mail::send('clientinfo.contact',['name' => 'shweta'],function($message){
            $message->to('myemail@gmail.com','Some Name')->subject('Welcome!')->from('otheremail@example.com');
           });
```

mail.php file :

```
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
    'from' => ['address' => 'someone@example.com', 'name' => 'Some  One Sender'],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
 'pretend' => false,

];
```

Please help me through this.

Comment: Hey, look into this https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en and enable less secure apps in the gmail account that you're using.

Comment: I have done this, but still no email sent. is this a problem that i an using `'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),` in mail.php file, but actually in my .env  file mail host is `MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com` ?

Comment: Umm not sure..check your log filed for errors. Also consider using Mandrill and Mailgun or such services, they provide free credits to start with. I personally use Postmark App for transactional mails. https://postmarkapp.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you install Guzzle to your project by adding the following line to your composer.json file:

> "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"

and editing your .env file with real email-id and password. Also, enable, less secure apps for that email-id as told by @Bharat Geleda

then your above code will run properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

1. I enabled two step verification on may gmail account
2. created separate apps password for my app here (screenshot below) (https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords)
3. I that password into my laravel .env file and it worked.

screenshot
just select "Other(custom name)" on the "select app" and it will generate a password for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MAIL_PORT=587` instead of the default mail_port in your `.env` file.