# Laravel 5 Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com in windows 7

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

When I user mail function in laravel, show me this error

> Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>
> ## 10060]

This is my `.env` file config

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myacount@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Try to change this MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

With

MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail

Comment: show me this error again

Comment: ok set this 'encryption' => 'ssl',   and env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION','tls'),

Comment: and also try to enable this also https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps.

Comment: show me this error again

Comment: what kind of error the same as you listed above or something else

try to run composer update once

Comment: from where  you can not send the mail, your pc[with XAMPP] Or shared hosting ?

Comment: Check windows firewall ? `host has failed to respond`it's message not for credentials, it's for initial connection.,

Comment: try to change port to one of these 25 - 465 (MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null)

Comment: I use wamp and disable firewall and try port 25 without encryption but show me error agian

Comment: Have you tried clearing the config cache? `php artisan config:clear` The settings in your post are exactly the same as mine, they are fine. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: show me this error again

Answer (score 4):

- In your local PC(with xampp/wamp) try the following steps if you want to work with Gmail

  1. https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps give permission for lesser secured app
  2. change your config like this

> ```
> MAIL_DRIVER='sendmail'
> MAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com' Or '173.194.65.108'
> MAIL_PORT=587
> MAIL_USERNAME='expense@blabla.com'
> MAIL_PASSWORD="secret"
> MAIL_ENCRYPTION="tls"
> ```

3. here important is driver - sendmail
4. Clear you config -

> ```
> Artisan::call('view:clear');
>  Artisan::call('route:clear');
>  Artisan::call('config:clear');
>  Artisan::call('cache:clear');
>  Artisan::call('config:cache');
> ```
>
> N.B - your cmd will be like: php artisan view:clear .....etc. Its important to clear your cache you change in .env . Me personally also restart the xampp as I read somewhere .env files load when apache starts!

5. Now try to send the mail , it should work if your network administrator did not blocked it[unintentionally! In my cases he even do not know for which change it stopped to sending mail]
6. I use these steps with laravel 5.2 and it worked fine but recently something is changed by either google Or My network administrator so its not sending mail from xampp but working fine in shared hosting.

N.B- I listed these because at least it worked on real hosting for which I spent much time to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but show me error :   `Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified`
]

Answer (score 0):

Just restart your XAMPP (both Apache and MySQL), and run again PHP Artisan, and your good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install Guzzle to your project by adding the following line to your composer.json file:

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"
```

reference [Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33565840/connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-com-laravel)